# Characteristic polynomial formulae

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've found a couple of interesting formulae for the characteristic polynomial $c_A(x)$ of matrices in the form of
$$A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

> That is
>   $$c_A(x)=(-1)^n(x^n-1)$$

Are there any similar formulae for some special kinds of matrices for quick reference?

Comment: Google "companion matrix". What you wrote is precisely the companion matrix of the polynomial $\;\pm(x^n-1)\;$ ...

Comment: See also [Circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking at a special case of a companion matrix.
Have a look here: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).